# Apache Spark: ClassNotFoundException: scala.Some while resolving class JavaSerializer.scala

Tags: scala, rest, apache-spark, scalatra

I am trying to expose an Apache Spark ML code as a REST service using Scalatra.

But while calling the GET on the REST endpoint, I receive the following error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Some at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]

Do I need to add some additional dependencies?

I have the following dependencies listed in my SBT file:

```
  lazy val scalatraVersion = "2.3.0"
  lazy val sparkVersion = "2.0.0"
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % scalatraVersion,
    "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-json" % scalatraVersion,
    "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-commands" % scalatraVersion,
    "org.json4s"   %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.9",
    "ch.qos.logback"    %  "logback-classic"   % "1.1.3"            ,
    "org.eclipse.jetty" %  "jetty-webapp"      % "9.2.10.v20150310",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.4",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion,
    "com.github.fommil.netlib" % "all" % "1.1.2"
  )
```

In my scala code `IssuePredictor.predict()`, I am trying to load the CrossValidatorModel from an already saved file. And this is where the error is thrown:
*(I know this because, the println statements before this line are printed, but those after it aren't)*

```
val cvModel = CrossValidatorModel.load("/Users/Bjghosh/MyFiles/Apache Spark/ml/tables/IssuePredictorCVModelNB_2.0")
```

I call my scala code that loads the model, gets the prediction and returns, as shown below:

```
class ScalatraStep1 extends ScalatraServlet  {

  notFound { "Route not implemented" }

  get("/predict/:rawText") {
    Try { params("rawText").toString }  match {
      case Success(id) => { println(s"Predict rawText: ${params("rawText")} ")
                            val predictor = new IssuePredictor
                            val prediction = predictor.predict(params("rawText"))
                             s"Prediction for rawText: ${params("rawText")} = $prediction} "
                          }
      case Failure(e) => BadRequest(reason = "Can't understand rawText")
    }
  }
}
```

**Error Trace**

> ERROR org.apache.spark.util.Utils - Exception encountered
>   **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Some**  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   **org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]**  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(AccumulatorV2.scala:167)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply(AccumulatorV2.scala:166)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply(AccumulatorV2.scala:166)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1253)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2.readObject(AccumulatorV2.scala:166)
>   [spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
>   [spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
>   [spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:253)
>   [spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
>   12:07:36.845 [Executor task launch worker-0] ERROR
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Exception in task 0.0 in stage
>   0.0 (TID 0) java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Some     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1260)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2.readObject(AccumulatorV2.scala:166)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:253)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_25]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
>   **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Some**   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   **org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]**  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(AccumulatorV2.scala:167)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply(AccumulatorV2.scala:166)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply(AccumulatorV2.scala:166)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1253)
>   ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]

Regards,
Bhaskar

Comment: i do have same issue , Did you find any solution ?